# Determine name of program which is closed slowly at shutdown

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

When I shutdown my computer (Windows 7), sometimes (~50%) I see the typical screen that a program can´t be closed, and, whether I want to wait for it or just kill the process.

The problem is, if I see this screen, it is only for a split second, probably because the program has finished it´s work then and was closed successfully.

It is too fast to read the program name.  Is there any way to show it longer, or any log of it, etc.,
just something to know which program is the cause of this?

Comment: Do you not see the self-contradiction in asking which program closes slowly when you yourself state that it closes so _quickly_ that you cannot read its name as it goes by?

Comment: Well, it is slow enough to make the message appear, but quick enough to close then...

Comment: it diplays something with "Uploader", but there is no process named ...Uploader...exe, that´s why i would like to know what it shows me there.

Comment: I never found out how to solve my initial question, but solved the problem another way. Because i´ve gotten more and more nervous about malware (because of the word "Uploader"), i finally made some effort of sniffing and setting up a bunch of small fake servers with hosts-file-redirection to try to make programs hang/crash if they want to communicate with the internet before shutdown (because they got "bad" data). It actually succeeded: Valve´s Steam was the "malware" which was reported as "Screenshot Uploader". (Yes, now i think it could be categorized as real malware)

Answer (score 1):

if your computer seems to shut down slowly (or not at all) or start up slowly, or if it doesn't enter power-saving modes, it's possible that a program or device driver is interfering with Windows power settings. You can use Performance Information and Tools to try to detect these programs or device drivers.

To check for performance issues

> Open Performance Information and Tools by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type Performance Information and Tools, and then, in the list of results, click Performance Information and Tools.
>
> In the left pane, click Advanced tools.
>
> In Advanced Tools, under Performance issues, click any issues that are listed.

Read the information in the dialog box that appears to learn which programs or drivers are causing problems.

---

If a program or driver prevents your computer from turning off quickly

You can try the following tasks to fix the problem:

> 1. Close the program before shutting down. It's possible that the problem occurs only if the program is running. Try closing the program before shutting down Windows, and then see if your computer turns off properly.
> 2. Check with the manufacturer of the program or driver for an update. A newer version of the program might include a resolution to the problem.

If these options don't solve the problem, then the program or driver might be incompatible with Windows. If you installed the program or device yourself and you no longer use it, consider removing the device, or uninstalling the program or driver.

Comment: I can shut down without problems, and the shutdown speed is not the problem. The question is just which program causes the message (if i know, i wouldn´t disable it)